# Run a .py file using a URL/API with a parameter(UserId)

Tags: python, api, flask

I am a novice developer working on a python code. I need to call a .py file using an API/URL and in the URL, I need to pass a 'UserId' in the parameter. How can I achieve the same ? It would be of great help if you could point me in the correct direction. I have written the below dummy code for better understanding.

Thank you so much.

```
from flask import Flask, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello():
    args = request.args
    UId = args.get('UserId')
    print('Hello '+str(UId))
    return (UId )


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: If you want to manually pass parameters to your "/" endpoint, you have to add a query string at the end of the url, for instance something like "http://localhost:8080?userId=13", source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For general use you can create dictionary for api parameters and pass them into your request like below;

```
api_endpoint = "api_url"

user_params = {,
    "'UserId'": 123123,
}


response = requests.get(url=api.endpoint, parameters=user_params)
```